# Site aligned to left on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, web, alignment, responsive

I have setup my dev site for desktop looks beautiful! but then when i go to mobile it is aligned to left with an empty space in the right.

My first thought was because the logo at top is too big and that causes to have that empty space at the right so i reduce the width without solving my issue.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lh3ldx455m7ohzc/error.jpg?dl=0

you can see my dev site here:
http://dev.pixlgraphx.com/dynmulti/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is related to you specifying the viewport twice.

You have:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
.
.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Try removing that second viewport line, leaving just the first. It seems to be upsetting the page scaling, at least it was for me.